# Brute force script with for loops without itertools

Tags: python, loops, brute-force

New to python. Working on loops. Trying to build simple brute force without using ready modules.
Here is the code:

```
numbers=[1,2,3]
password_to_guess = [1,3]
x=', '.join(map(str, password_to_guess))
password = [0]
pass_len=3

for n in range (pass_len):  
    for i in numbers:
        password[n] = i
        print (password)
        i+=1
        y=', '.join(map(str, password))

    if x==y:
        print("stop")
        break
    else:
        password[n]=0
        password.append(0)
```

Here is what i got in result:

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
[0, 1]
[0, 2]
[0, 3]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 2]
[0, 0, 3]
```

Can't figure out how to fix it so it will give me this:

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[2, 1]
[2, 2]
[2, 3]
and so on to the pass_len
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your looking for?

```
numbers=[1,2,3]
password = [0]
pass_len = 3

for i in numbers :
    password [0] = i
    print (password)
password.append (0)
for n in range (1, pass_len + 1) :
    password [0] = n
    for i in numbers :
        password [1] = i
        print (password)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I came up with. It takes a different approach using generators but it will automatically check every possible solution. The only import is sys to escape the nested loop at the end of the code.

```
import sys
numbers = (1,2,3)
password_to_guess = (1,3)

def permutations(iterable, r = None):
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    r = n if r is None else r
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = list(range(n))
    cycles = list(range(n, n-r, -1))
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
    while n:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            cycles[i] -= 1
            if cycles[i] == 0:
                indices[i:] = indices[i+1:] + indices[i:i+1]
                cycles[i] = n - i
            else:
                j = cycles[i]
                indices[i], indices[-j] = indices[-j], indices[i]
                yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
                break
        else:
            return

def perm_list():
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        yield permutations(numbers , i)

perm_list = perm_list()

for i in perm_list:
    for j in i:
        if j == password_to_guess:
            print(f"{j} is the password")
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: The permutation function is one contained in a module, but it is really just a function you can write.

Answer (score 0):

Simple naive depth first search recursive function.  Not good for performance or passwords of large length.

Works by taking a list, and calling itself with `rec(list+[...each element in numbers])`, so:
`rec([])` will in turn
call  rec([]+[1]),
calls rec([1]+[1]),
calls rec([1,1]+[1]),
returns after [1,1,1] because pass_len reached,
calls rec([1,1]+[2]) ...etc
If length is reached, means no password found in this branch, so return None
If pwd(s)==x, then password found, return pwd(s), and return all the way back up the tree.

```
def pwd(p):
    return ', '.join(map(str, p))

numbers=[1,2,3]
password_to_guess = [1,3]
x = pwd(password_to_guess)
pass_len = 3

def rec(s):
    if pwd(s)==x: #password found, return password
        return s
    if len(s)==pass_len: #length reached, return Nothing
        return None
    for n in numbers:
        ret = rec(s+[n]) #call myself with n appended
        if ret!=None: #password found, return immediately
            return ret

print(pwd(rec([])))
```